# Toyota Tacoma squeaky front shock

Tags: toyota, suspension, noise

I recently purchased a Toyota Tacoma 2008. It has a one inch lift kit with aftermarket rims and tires. The problem is that the front shocks squeak loudly when going over a curb for example.

Any ideas on the source of the squeak, or thoughts on what I can look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shocks are an aftermarket brand they may have urethane mounting bushings. Urethane generally offer longer life and better performance. The draw back is that they can some times squeek. During installation a dab of grease will abate this for awhile. You can try to add a little WD-40 to see if it helps. If this resolves the issue remove the affected shock mount and apply some white grease and reinstall it.